# Why is the before pseudo selector is having different result when the navbar class's position is changed to relative?

Tags: html, css

Here in the first case, I have made the navbar class inactive by commenting it out in vs code.

[image]

The result in the live server is as follows

[image]

Now I made the navbar class active and the position is set, relative
[image]

Now the results are as follows
[image]

The background color fits the size of the navigation bar.

I am not getting what is actually happening when the position of the navbar is set as relative.
How is the background color fits in the second case?

Here is the snippet for case 1:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: white;
    }
    /* .navbar{
       position:relative;
    } */
    .navbar::before{
        content:"";
        background-color: black;
        position:absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, asperiores.
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Case 2:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: white;
    }
    .navbar{
       position:relative;
    }
    .navbar::before{
        content:"";
        background-color: black;
        position:absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, asperiores.
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::before` pseudo-element appears before the content of the element to which it is applied.

`.navbar` is therefore an ancestor of `.navbar::before`.

Your `::before` pseudo-element is absolutely positioned.

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to their nearest *positioned* ancestor.

(Where *positioned* means "has a value for the `position` property which is not `static`, which is the default.)

When you change `.navbar` from `position: static` (the default) to `position: relative` (your explicit choice) you make it *positioned*.

When it becomes *positioned* the pseudo-element becomes positioned with respect to that element instead of whatever it was before.